# I've setup SVN to automatically update the revision number in a txt file but only on changes to file. I'd like it to update Rev on every commit

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

So if the text file is altered and I commit those changes, the $Revison 12345 number updates to match.

How can I have the revision number in the text file update when it was other files/folders changes that were being committed?

Thanks

My setup is:

In SVN Settings press edit on the Subversion Configuration File

Uncomment the lines:

enable-auto-props = yes

Add the line:

VERSION.txt = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id Rev URL;

Create VERSION.txt in your project and store in it

AppNameVersion(1.2.3.4)

$Revision: 144 $

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't reinvent the wheel, don't store existing (in repo) data in one more additional independent location even inside repo
2. You have to have this data *only* for use with sources **outside the repo**, thus - getting and storing rev-info is a task for your build|deploy tool
3. You can get GlobalRevision at any time with at least two slightly different ways:

   - Pure Subversion with [`svnversion`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) call
   - If you have TSVN (according to tagging), you have [SubWCRev](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html), which you can use for complex processing of data, than "plain numbers" in svnversion,if you want it